# In objective-c what kind of method is this?

Tags: objective-c

Going through some code and found a method like this in an iOS project. What is this?

Define:

```
void updateThing(){
   //....
}
```

Used like this:

```
updateThing();
```

Comment: What is the problem here? It looks like a normal C program which is valid in Objective-C.

Comment: Please elaborate the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a method. It's a C function, something that's part of C, the language objective-c is based on.

They have nothing to do with Objective-C classes or objects, although a C function in Obj-C can both take Objective-C objects as arguments and return them.

C functions are defined as follows:

```
returntype name(argtype arg1, argtype arg2) {
}
```

They are global (not called within some kind of scope), and have no `self`.